# add string literal and .net var in a alt tag

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to use a string and a .net element in a alt tag but I can't get them to work together without any spacing 
for example

```
alt="someText @model.item"
```

works fine but what I really need is

```
alt="someText@model.item"
```

for a result of someTextModeitem not someTextM odeitem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an explicit code expression:

```
alt="someText@(model.item)"
```

Otherwise Razor thinks you're trying to use an email address.